# How to Align Web Form Text and Inputs Separately?

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment

I'm looking for the most efficient way to code a fairly simple html form layout I've done a mockup of.

So far I've thought of a number of ways to code this but they all seem rather cumbersome when implemented.

Basically what I'm trying to put into action is plain text aligned to the right and form imputes aligned to the left with a line in the center of both. Below is an image that should give an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: So what mark-up are you using? Have you prepared a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to work with?

Comment: So what's the question? Did you need us to hop into doing this for you?

Comment: Nice image, what have you tried so far? Do you have an example code?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach, though I think you could have helped yourself a great deal more, by showing previous attempts and explaining problems you had. However:

```
form {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 40em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #3f3a27;
    background: #f4f0e5 url(http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/test.png) 35% 0 repeat-y;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

label, input[type=text], select {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 0.6em;    
}

label {
    width: 30%;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0 10% 0 0;
}

label:after {
    content: ': ';
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 40%;
}

select {
    width: 20%;
}

fieldset {
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
```

With the HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="fullName">Full name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fullName" />
        <label for="companyName">Company</label>
        <input type="text" id="companyName" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="select">Select</label>
        <select id="select" name="select">
            <option>Option one</option>
            <option>Option two</option>
        </select>
        <label for="t1">Text input 1</label>
        <input id="t1" type="text" />
        <label for="t2">Text input 1</label>
        <input id="t2" type="text" />
        <label for="t3">Text input 1</label>
        <input id="t3" type="text" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KnqG2/).

Comment: Outstanding! Exactly what I was looking for. Sorry if I was a bit vague in not sharing my existing code but this helps a lot!

Comment: Has this, or any other answer, solved your problem? If so please consider accepting, or up-voting useful answers.

Comment: I would but it seems due to being a new member my privilege level doesn't allow for voting-up answers.

Comment: If your problem is solved, though, you *should* be able to *accept* an answer. (But ***only*** if your problem is solved. If it's *not*, then you need to edit your question to explain what's still not right about the offered solutions.)

Answer (score 1):

CSS & HTML http://jsfiddle.net/27cdz/3/

Comment: Thanks for putting this together!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic form with minimal style

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <div class="line">
        <label for="input">Full Name</label>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="text" size="30" name="input">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <label for="input">Company</label>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="text" size="30" name="input">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <label for="nselect">Dropdown Menu</label>
        <div class="input">
            <select name="select">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <label for="input">Text 1</label>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="text" size="30" name="input">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <label for="input">Text 2</label>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="text" size="30" name="input">
        </div>Save
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <label for="input">Text 3</label>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="text" size="15" name="input">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
form {
    margin:10px 0;
}

label {
    color: #404040;
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 130px;
}

label, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
}

input, textarea, select {
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    color: #808080;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 210px;
}

select {
    height: 27px;
    line-height: 27px;
}

form .input {
    margin-left: 150px;
}

form .line {
    margin-bottom: 18px;
}
```

Test
http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/qxMVd/

Comment: Several things, `for=` works with input `id=`, not `name=`. Also, I see a lot of unnecessary divs in your markup. Can't say I can +1 this one, sorry mate.

Comment: @Truth OP asked for how to align input elements, not a complete form framework that he can copy paste (we don't know what he has done). My solution is just a case of how it can be done, and as for the divs included in the markup they are included to properly separate the form elements in a block-line - as seen on any major website (like google, twitter, facebook - reliable for semantics and fullproof).

Comment: Obviously, it's just not a good solution. I understand the need for a wrapper for both label and input, but why the input wrapper? If you have only one element inside of a div, you probably don't need it (in this case, you don't). And also, if you're already using a `for=` attribute, at least use it correctly with the corresponding `id=` attribute.

Comment: @Truth That was not the question though, we don't know what he has already done, the title of the question is **How to Align Web Form Text and Inputs Separately?** not how to make one, and as for the `.input` wrapper, it is used to keep a consistent margin left of 150px that doesn't break upon container resize. I take note of how all the big boys do it, because they are done for a reason and from my own testing this is the best way possible to maintain a proper margin between browsers (including IE, which i have to support at work).

Comment: Thanks for putting this together! This helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the display values of [`table, table-row, and table-cell`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display#Values) to keep the markup as semantically neat as possible: See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8YpKY/7/)

Comment: +1. Though I recommend you adding IDs and `for=` attributes for the input names and labels.

Comment: Actually, after trying each one of these implementations out with my existing code, this one seemed to work best for our proposes. I've ran into an issue though when it comes to adding radio buttons. All <imput> tags break onto a new line and while that works for text boxes, I'd like to have radio buttons display on one line and floated to the right. How can this be done? Thanks once again!

Comment: Here is an [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8YpKY/11/) with inline radio buttons and a couple slight modifications to the CSS that should make it more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

I have it like you wanted it: http://jsfiddle.net/XURye/

With the same colors and every position is correct too!

Comment: Thanks so much! I appreciate the added effort you put in to applying the same colors and positioning!

Answer (score 0):

This minimal two selectors CSS from this [Drupal post](https://www.drupal.org/node/2422361#comment-9599699) worked really well:

```css
.form-item {
  padding: 10px 0 10px 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.form-item label {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```