# Moving form elements into a position where they look stacked

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment

I have a login form I'm creating... The problem is, I can't align the text boxes and text correctly.

It looks like this at the moment:

[image: Align fail]

But i need it to look like:

[image: Correctly aligned, Text is all different sizes but text and textboxes are stacked up and not further to the left]

This is very hard to explain. What I really want is for the text and text boxes to stay on the same X axis but the Y axis can be changed.

I think it requires a table, however I do not know how to use those. If it does require one, an explanation of how to use a table to align these forms would be great.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just give the labels a width.

Comment: @Joerg I wrapped the text in `<label>` tags and set the width of the `<label>` tag to 100px with `label { width: 100px; }` however the problem still persists.

Comment: Have you looked at these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10965155/82548http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204002/align-form-elements-in-css, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8695327/82548 (among others)? Also, what's your (representative/minimal/"[MCVE](http://api.jquery.com/help/mcve)")?

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes, I have. The problem is, When there is a slight difference in the problem, I end up getting confused. That's why I asked my own question with my own details.

Comment: But you haven't shown enough information for us to offer a different, more precise solution, hence my question regarding your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `text-align` with `float/display: inline-block`. Inputs are inside labels. Example.

```
<label>
    <span>username:</span>
    <input>
</label>

<label>
    <span>password:</span>
    <input>
</label>

<label>
    <span>country:</span>
    <select>
        <option>option
    </select>
</label>

<style>
    label {display: block; overflow: hidden; margin: 5px 0 0; height: 24px; line-height: 24px;}
    label > * {float: left;}
    label span {width: 90px; text-align: right; margin-right: 5px;}
    label span + * {width: 100px; height: 20px; line-height: 20px; padding: 0;}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tb34rv1x/

Or the second (of many) option. Inputs are outside `label`s:

```
<label for="a">username</label>
<input id=a>

<label for="b">password:</label>
<input id=b>

<label for="c">country:</label>
<select id="c">
    <option>option
</select>

<style>
    label {float: left; clear: left; width: 100px; text-align: right; margin-right: 10px;}
    label + * {float: left;}
    * {margin-top: 5px;}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tb34rv1x/1/

Comment: How can I center this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tb34rv1x/2/ - wrap that by `form` and add `display: table; margin: auto;`

Comment: THanks, But the problem is it's not exactly centered. How do I know? The submit button is in the center of the screen, A little bit more of the form is on the left rather than the right.

Comment: @MarkieJonesWTF: because labels has width and text, label's content doesn't fit well into this size. I think it's not a problem, and if it is, use `display: table/table-cell` values instead of floats.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are new to web dev just use the teble.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First name: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fname"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last name: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lname"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is jFiddle: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/c6242/3860/)

For more advanced version use div-s. Like [Other post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387392/how-to-get-these-two-divs-side-by-side)

Comment: No, form data aren't the table data. It seems to be easier to understand, but it isn't semantic.